# No alert displayed when UIRequiresPersistentWiFi is included

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I am currently using Xcode 8.2 and have included the key: `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` in my info.plist file.

According to others, when the user is not connected to WiFi, the user should be prompted with an alert to turn WiFi on. However, this alert is not showing up when this key is included. I don't know if the key has been deprecated in later versions of Xcode. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why the message is not showing, and also help in finding a way to display the message.

In Apple's documentation it says this for the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` key:

> The inclusion of this key lets the system know that it should display the network selection dialog if it detects any active Wi-Fi hot spots. It also lets the system know that it should not attempt to shut down the Wi-Fi hardware while your app is running.

Comment: But says nothing about any dialog here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html and in fact my impression is that there has been no such dialog since maybe iOS 8.

Comment: @matt if you were to go to this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html. It says that it should display the network selection dialog.

Comment: Yup. But I'm saying that I'm not sure they've obeyed that as a hard and fast rule recently.

Comment: If Airplane Mode is on (and wi-fi is off) and UIRequiresPersistentWiFi is present, then an alert is displayed saying "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data".